# Ubuntu 14.04 crashes

Tags: 14.04

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 (clean install). I like it a lot, but the system would freeze and computer sometimes would even restart by itself. Does anyone else have the same issue and how it can be resolved? The crashes would happen about every 30 minutes, but mostly when I watch youtube videos (but this could be coincedence). I installed 12.04, and everything is fine now, but I would really like to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I currently don't have the same issue, but I've only been running Ubuntu 14.04 for less than a week now. Can you try to open your terminal and run the `top` command to see if there is a process that's using excessive CPU?

If there is a process entitled `compiz` or `Xorg`, you may have an issue with your graphics driver that's over-stressing your CPU.

If Ubuntu can't fully access the graphics card in order to render objects on the screen, it forces the CPU to emulate the job of the GPU and that pots a lot of stress on it. It may be overheating on your computer and causes it to crash (I don't even know if that's possible on most modern computers/laptops).

And sorry: I would have just posted this as a comment, but I don't have enough rep.